# Permissions depending on how you login: ssh/su/sudo

Tags: ssh, security, sudo, su

As `user` I have access to a remote linux machine where I can:

```
sudo su - other_user
```

Among other things, this allows me to add my own public key to `authorized_keys` for `other_user`, which effectively also lets me `ssh` into this machine as `other_user`.

What's interesting is that, as `user`, I am **not** allowed to do the following directly, since I do **not** (nor I am supposed to) know `other_user`'s  password:

```
su - other_user
```

Does this security policy make sense? What difference does it make to **not** know the password for `other_user` if I **can** `ssh` **or** `sudo su -` into `other_user`?

More generally, what differences exist in terms of what you can and cannot do depending on how you log in as `other_user`?

Comment: I was wondering the same thing when I was troubleshooting a family member's MAC via terminal. I can sudo su - root, but was unable to su - root (it was not accepting the root password and I know I typed it in right!)

Comment: sudo access is maintained in `/etc/sudoers` where you decided who you want to give access to sudo. It is level of security that you want to set for your users. You can allow yourself via authorized_key or maybe more damage but remember there are logs to monitor these activities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Does this security policy make sense?

Yes and no.  No in the sense that it does not protect other_user's data.  But it does protect other_user's password.  This may seem inconsequential, but that means there is at least one important thing you cannot do: change the password so that the person who normally uses the account can't access it.

Another consequence of using `su` and keeping passwords secret is that `/var/log/auth.log` should contain stuff like this:

```
Nov  8 08:08:10 ...(su:session): session opened for user other_user by (uid=1066)
[...]
Nov  8 09:38:10 ...(su:session): session closed for user other_user
```

Presuming your uid is 1066 and your password is also secret, if anything unsavoury happened to `other_user`'s stuff during those 90 minutes, there is a strong case to be made that you did it.  I've done work places where **log**in details like this were used to identify people doing things they knew they were not supposed to do.

Comment: If I understand this correctly, are you saying that I can't change `other-user`'s password if I login as him via `sudo su - other-user` or `ssh`, **unless** I know her password?

Comment: Yep.  You've `su`'d as root (so you don't need a password, which you would if you just used `su` without `sudo`), but if you now try `passwd` (to change the password of the account you su'd to as root) you'll have to enter the current password first.  To change a password without knowing the current one, you'd have to `sudo passwd other_user`.

Answer (score 3):

Since you can only run `su - other_user` to get access to that account, there are things you can't do. You can only run the login shell of that account or programs that the login shell allows you to run. This doesn't make a difference if the login shell is a general shell like `sh` or `bash`, but it does if the shell is a [restricted shell](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Restricted_shell) or some kind of special-purpose program.

Assuming that the account doesn't have a restricted shell, you can add a public key of yours to `~/.ssh/authorized_keys` to let you log in remotely. The administrator could disable that if they wanted, either by making the home directory not writable by the user (which is not common in general-purpose accounts, because it's very inconvenient for the user), or by making the directory `.ssh` immutable, or via options in the server configuration.

Since you don't know the password, you won't be able to change it: the `passwd` command prompts for the current password.

Not knowing the password also means that the administrator can revoke your access without having to change the password. They'll have to search for backdoors (SSH key, setuid file), but they only need to check the files on that machine for that, which is feasible, unlike making you forget the password.